# read a password-protected page

Tags: php, perl, ssl

I'm trying to read specific div-elements of a website with a script either written in php or perl.

Unfortunately, the page requests a login before those specific site can be read. As I can see, it's ssl-protected. I'm not looking for a complete solution, I just need a hint regarding the best way to tell the script the informations needed for logging in (user+password), before reading parts of the sourcecode of the page that comes afterwards.

I'm not quite sure if it's better to do this with PERL or PHP, so i have tagged this question with both of these languages.

Comment: PHP (or whatever really) with **Curl** -using a [cookie jar](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/examples/cookiejar.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mojo::UserAgent](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/UserAgent) (see [cookbook](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#USER_AGENT)) has a built-in cookie jar and can do SSL if you have [IO::Socket::SSL](https://metacpan.org/module/IO%3a%3aSocket%3a%3aSSL) installed. It has a [DOM parser](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/DOM) which can easily use [CSS3](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/DOM/CSS) selectors to traverse the returned result. And if that wasn't good enough, the whole thing can be used non-blocking (if that's something you need).

Mojo::UserAgent and the other tools listed above are parts of the [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us) suite of tools. It's a Perl library, and I would certainly recommend Perl for this task since it is a more general purpose language than PHP is.

Here is a very simplistic example to get the text from all the links that are inside a div with a class myclass

```
use Mojo::UserAgent;
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;

$ua->post( 'http://mysite.com/login' => form => { ... } );
my @link_text =
  $ua->get( 'http://mysite.com/protected/page' )
     ->res
     ->dom('div.myclass a')
     ->text
     ->each;
```

In fact, running this shell command may be enough to get you started (depending on permissions)

```
curl -L cpanmin.us | perl - -n  Mojolicious IO::Socket::SSL
```